# Android not calling first method/skipping first method

Tags: java, android, azure, android-studio, face-api

I'm using Azure Face API for facial recognition, some of my methods are only running correctly in debug mode:

```
public void detectFace(MenuItem item){
        getPicture();
        startFaceRecognition();
    }
```

I first noticed the issue with the code above. The getPicture() method does not seem to run if the second method is called after, though does run if the startFaceRecognition() is called from within getPicture().

```
   public void addFace(MenuItem item){
        getPicture();

        AddFaceParams params = new AddFaceParams("family", "personIdCode", "", currentPhotoPath);
        new AddFaceTask().execute(params);
    }
```

The second piece of code takes a picture and then sends the picture with relevant information to Azure with a HTTP request in an asynchronous task. I believe the issue is the getPicture() method isn't being called unless there's a breakpoint placed inside the method. It works if I step through the method, but not if it is run by itself.

Would this be some form of timing issue?
I am new to Java and Android development.